# SQL Server Selecting and displaying all duplicate data based on 3 criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server, I would like to select all rows that have code x on the same date.
For example:  The records must have the same ID, on the same date, and the same code (code x).
I would then like to select only these rows (not just the 1 row with the ID that has a duplicate, but both rows that are duplicates).

To be displayed:

```
ID 3   10/1/16  Code X
ID 3   10/1/16  Code X
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT ID,Date,CODE
FROM (SELECT ID,Date,CODE
      FROM my table
      WHERE code = 'x' and date between '10-01-2016' and '10-31-2016'
      GROUP BY ID,date,code
      HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 1
     ) as T1
JOIN
    my table as T2 on
    T1.ID = T2.ID and 
    T1.Date = T2.Date and
    T1.code = T2.code
where code ='x' and date between '10-01-2016' and '10-31-2016'
group by ID,date,code
```

Comment: My apologies, that looked to be formatted much better before I submitted.

Comment: What is the data type and size of the `date` field? Perhaps the query processor will handle it, but using `date` as a field name does not sound very good.

Comment: @liturgist The field is actually service date. 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

```
select      *

from       (SELECT      count       (*) over (partition by  ID,date)                    as group_records
                       ,dense_rank  ()  over (order by      ID,date)                    as group_id
                       ,row_number  ()  over (partition by  ID,date order by getdate()) as row_within_group
                       ,t.*

            FROM        mytable t

            WHERE       code = 'x' 
                    and date between '10-01-2016' and '10-31-2016' 
            ) t

where       group_records > 1

order by    group_id
           ,row_within_group
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, You can use this query:

```
select * from my_table where `ID` in
        (select `ID` from my_table group by `ID`,`Date`,`CODE` having count(*)>1)
    AND `Date` in
        (select `Date` from my_table group by `ID`,`Date`,`CODE` having count(*)>1)
    AND `CODE` in
        (select `CODE` from my_table group by `ID`,`Date`,`CODE` having count(*)>1)
```

I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: Thanks would I just add the date and code criteria as 2 more and statements?

Comment: where code ='x' and date between '10-01-2016' and '10-31-2016'

Comment: So, then you can apply a filter using WHERE after whole selection thing when you found all duplicates.